# c# - check if array position is null or a space?

Tags: c#

I need to check if the final place of an array is equal to a space " ". My code below throws an out of range exception and the words variable includes a space at the end through a regex pattern.

Code:

```
string[] words = pattern.Split(input);
int limit = words.Count();

if(words[limit] == " ")
{ limit = limit - 1;  }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    string[] words = pattern.Split(input);
    int limit = words.Count();

    if(words[limit-1] == " ")
    { limit = limit - 1;  }
```

The array position needs to be -1 when a count() is used. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`.Count()` returns the number of elements in your array, but the first elements index is 0, so the last index should be `words.Count()-1`

Comment: The final element will equal to 'limit' in this case. How do it write an if-statement if final element == (" ") ?

Comment: Thanks for that. I totally spaced out on that one. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following code. The `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` method checks if a given string only consists null or white space characters.

```
    string[] words = pattern.Split(input);
    int limit = words.Length;

    if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(words[limit-1]))
    {
      limit-=1; //edit value of limit based on your own logic
    }
```